# Error to get the access token in facebook using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The code that I'm using :

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  echo 'No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. A user has not authorized your app yet.';
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Signed Request</h3>';
var_dump($helper->getSignedRequest());

echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
```

**Output:**
This only shows that:  No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. A user has not authorized your app yet

I am using my page's `app_id and app_secret`.

Comment: This means that you should autorize you application on your Facebook page in order to allow to do anything in your Facebook account. The details are in Facebook help: https://www.facebook.com/help/262314300536014/

Comment: Output itself displays the solution, authorize your app

Comment: Could you give me direction to authorize it?

Comment: Should i mention the App Domains, what is that??

Comment: @SergeyLebedev, I did not get any help from you documentation.

Comment: read the docs about facebook login, that is what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 0):

The example you are using "(...) covers obtaining an access token and signed request FROM WITHIN THE CONTEXT OF AN APP CANVAS (...)".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_canvas

Context of an app canvas means that your app is embeded on Facebook (iframe).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669757/2911960

I assume you want to use the API on your website. Then you are looking for this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login