# How do I authorize a app in Facebook-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Very new to PHP and downloaded Facebook-PHP-SDK and I am trying to run a simple code I found online but I keep getting an error.  I have done lots of research on the problem, looked at similar questions on here and so for but have not been able to find anything that helps. It looks like I still need to authorize the app I created in Facebook Developers, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{}',
  'app_secret' => '{}',
  'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  echo 'No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.';
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Signed Request</h3>';
var_dump($helper->getSignedRequest());

echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
```

Error Message

```
No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.
```

Comment: See this, potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882664/error-to-get-the-access-token-in-facebook-using-php-sdk, it contains a link to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supplying the SDK with the required `app_id` and `app_secret` so it can't do anything. That's why it gives you an OAUTH error. ([fb-docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login))

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{}', // Here
  'app_secret' => '{}', // Here
  'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);
```

You need to get that data from your [facebook app configuration dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). And plug into this object.

example:

```
$app_id = "1234";
$app_secret = "foobar";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{$app_id}',
  'app_secret' => '{$app_secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
  ]);
```

Comment: I did that and I am still getting same error.  Is there maybe something on my facebook developer account I need to do that I am not doing?

Comment: Did you authorize the app in the app dashboard?

Comment: I became a verified admin then turned the status of my app to live.  Is that what you mean?  I think the problem could also be that my program is not getting an access token so it returns null for the access token which causes the program to crash.

Comment: Can you try and echo out the `$access_token` variable immediatly after it is set? to see what the result is? You didn't post and error message from the `catch` statements so it seems that something is working there, or at least no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are all registered and managed at https://developers.facebook.com/ . Have you checked your settings there?

Comment: I created an app and the status is Live